# mapPartitions compile error: missing parameter type

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

I'm trying to read a stream from a Kafka source containing JSON records using a pattern from the book [Learning Spark](https://github.com/holdenk/learning-spark-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/BasicParseJsonWithJackson.scala):

```scala
import spark.implicits._
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.sql.types._
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import java.util.Date

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.experimental.ScalaObjectMapper
import com.fasterxml.jackson.module.scala.DefaultScalaModule
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationFeature

val spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("StreamingRetailTransactions").config("master", "local").getOrCreate()


val df = spark.readStream.
                format("kafka").
                option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", ...).
                option("subscribe", "transactions_load").
                option("kafka.security.protocol", "SASL_SSL").
                ...
                load()

case class Invoice(
                    invoiceNo: Int,
                    stockCode: Int,
                    description: String,
                    ...
                    storeId: Int,
                    transactionId: String
                  )
```

And then ...

```scala
val df2 = df.selectExpr("CAST(value AS String)").as[String]

val df3 = df2.mapPartitions(records => {

  val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
  mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
  mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

  records.flatMap(record => {
    try {
      Some(mapper.readValue(record, classOf[Invoice]))
    } catch {
      case e: Exception => None
    }
  })
}, true)

val query = df3.writeStream.format("console").start()
```

However, I'm running into this issue:

```
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[String] = [value: string]
<console>:63: error: missing parameter type
       val df3 = df2.mapPartitions(records => {
                                   ^
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method mapPartitions only takes a function:

```
func: Iterator[T] => Iterator[U]
```

as its parameter.

Try it after removing the `true` from the end:

```
val df3 = df2.mapPartitions(records => {

    val mapper = new ObjectMapper with ScalaObjectMapper
    mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false)
    mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)

    records.flatMap(record => {
      try {
        Some(mapper.readValue(record, classOf[Invoice]))
      } catch {
        case _: Exception => None
      }
    })
  })
```

Comment: The example source code has the boolean parameter, maybe this was removed in later versions of spark: https://github.com/holdenk/learning-spark-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/BasicParseJsonWithJackson.scala#L52

Comment: There never was one - you're copying `DStream` code and you're trying to apply it on a `Dataset` (Structure Streaming). That being said you wouldn't use this logic in Struct. Stream. in the first place (builtins will work better with smaller overhead).